# ruby module and class confusion

Tags: ruby, class, module

I'm learning ruby and I'm trying to figure out what is meant by the following definition:

```
class Rectangle::Square < Shape
```

So I am aware that Square is a subclass of Shape, but why the scope resolution operator? 
This is usually used to access classes and constants from a module in ruby, but here there is the class definition, so how could it already be located inside a module? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definition "opens" `Rectangle` class/module and adds a new class to it, `Square`. This is more or less equivalent to

```
class Rectangle
  class Square < Shape
  end
end
```

The only difference I can think of, is that your snippet will fail if `Rectangle` is not defined, and this snippet will not.

Comment: Other difference is constant lookup

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the code failing when `Rectangle` is not defined, there is another issue:

Within the `class Rectangle` block, you can refer to the other class by just `Square`. Outside of it, you have to refer to it as `Rectangle::Square`. If you define it as `class Rectangle::Square`, though, you'll have to refer to the class as `Rectangle::Square`. Same goes for all other classes (and other constants) that are namespaced in `Rectangle`. The reason you see this pattern quite often is that the code writers want to avoid fully qualifying the nested classes. It will be often that the outer module (`Rectangle` in this case) contains a few classes that need to interact with each other.

It's the same reason you can often see specs defined like this:

```
class Rectangle
  describe Square
  end
end
```

That way you can construct a square just by doing `Square.new`. If it was `describe Rectangle::Square`, then you will need to fully qualify it and do `Rectangle::Square.new`

Answer (score -1):

This is a synonym to

```
module Rectangle
  class Square < Shape
  end
end
```

Comment: Misleading, as there are subtle differences.